# Does jar file change the contents of an encoded text file, when we reimport it?

Tags: java, security, encoding, jar, encryption

I have a Java application where I need to protect contents in a text file before it is exported in a jar file. So I encode the file using BlowFish algorithm provided by "javax.crypto.Cipher". And I decrypt it on the fly.

Everything works fine when I am running the application from my workstation. But once I export the application as a jar file and run it. It throws up an error in the part of the code that tries to decrypt the contents of the protected text file. The error is:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Does export-jar-file-process alter the contents of the included text file in anyway like e.g. it's encoding?

Comment: "..protect contents in a text file before it is exported in a jar file."  If your code can decrypt it, and your code is in the clutches of a hacker, then the hacker can also decrypt it.

Comment: So I think I should have been more thorough in my wording. It is not extremely super-sensitive, it is one of those cases where we want the flexibility with "good-enough" security. We would be exposing only the class files through .jar. Also this text file is actually a lookup table & only through our API can the data be looked up.

Answer (score 0):

The Jar command and the java.util APIs to generate zips & jars do not deal with encodings -- they treat files as binary. I would look at your build process, to see if you have some property substitution filters etc. I've seen Maven and ANT mess up binary files with textual filenames... Incidentally, does your encoded file retail a .txt extension?

Comment: Yes it does have a .txt file extension.